# show two plot together in Matplotlib like show(fig1,fig2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In general, I don't have any problem to put two plots in a figure like `plot(a);plot(b)` in matplotlib. Now I am using a particular library which would generate a figure and I want to overlay with boxplot. Both are generated by matplotlib. So I think it should be fine but I can only see one plot. Here is the code. I am using [beeswarm](https://github.com/mgymrek/pybeeswarm) and here is [its ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb?create=1). I can only plot beeswarm or boxplot but not both in a figure. My main goal is trying to save column scatter plot and boxplot together as a figure in pdf. Thanks,

```
from beeswarm import beeswarm
fig=plt.figure()
figure(figsize=(5,7))
ax1=plt.subplot(111)
fig.ylim=(0,11)
d2 = np.random.random_integers(10,size=100)
beeswarm(d2,col="red",method="swarm",ax=ax1,ylim=(0,11))
boxplot(d2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the positioning of the box plot. The default positioning list starts with 1 what shifts the plot to 1 and your beeswarm plot sits on 0.

So the plots are in different places of your canvas.

I modified your code a little bit and that seems to solve your problem.

```
from beeswarm import beeswarm
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Here you may want to use ax1.set_ylim(0,11) instead fig.ylim=(0,11)
ax1.set_ylim(0,11)
d2 = np.random.random_integers(10,size=100)
beeswarm(d2,col="red",method="swarm",ax=ax1,ylim=(0,11))
boxplot(d2,positions=[0])
```

Cheers

Comment: With your code, boxplot still overwrites beeswarm. So I can only see boxplot. I update my question with the figure I want for clarity. Right now, I just get panda data from beeswarm and replot with `plot` command. Right now I am running your code inside ipython. I will try it without using ipython.

Comment: I change the answer properly addressing your issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I also change the order of the plot? I cannot use zorder in boxplot like I can do in plot.Thanks,